# All idempotents are central then $KG$ has no nilpotent

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, representation-theory, nilpotence, idempotents

Given $G$ a finite group and $K$ a field of characteristic zero such that all idempotents in $KG$ are central, is it true that $KG$ has no nilpotent element or equivalently $KG$ has only division ring in its Wedderburn decomposition?

Comment: Yes If there is a factor $M_r(D)$ with $r\geq 2$ in the decomposition, then any elementary matrix $E_{ij}$ is a non central idempotent...

Comment: @GreginGre I think you can turn that into an answer...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. If there is a factor $M_r(D)$ with $r\geq2$ in the decomposition, then any elementary matrix $E_{ii}$ is a non central idempotent.

Comment: I think you mean $E_{ii}$, as $E_{ij}$ is not idempotent unless $i=j$.

Comment: yes, of course. Edited.